# bootstrap's Jumbotron - can't see the bottom border when I set border, why is that?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, border

I'm new to bootstrap, and I set border to Jumbotron class and I see the border top, left and right, but can't see the border bottom, it's missing.

I found in bootstrap site this:  that I think I have that, but I have know idea how to reset this...
I want to see the border bottom, not to hide it.

I have a bootstrap.min.css file (in additon to my css file of course), but there's nothing in the bootstrap file that related to the borders or Jumbotron..
How can I reset the border bottom 0?

Thank you!

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in your post, e.g. a code snippet which reproduces your problem. Also, please specify the exact version of Bootstrap you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You bottom border might be under the bellow element. Check this example,

```css
.jumbotron{
    position: relative;
    padding:0 !important;
    margin-top:70px !important;
    background: #eee;
    margin-top: 23px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
 border:2px solid blue;
 //border-bottom:2px solid red;
}
.jumbotron .container-fluid{
    padding:0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="jumbotron" id="jumbo_block">
<h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h1>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <h3><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span></h3>
      <h4> Thursday 12:30</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <h3><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker icon-white"></span></h3>
      <h4> Kanyon</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <h3><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></h3>
      <h4>6 People</h4>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```